# how to generate array that shows reletionship between multiple classes?

Tags: php

I want a PHP script that scans PHP classes files in given directory(sub directories too) and generate relation ship between them in array form.
suppose a folder that contains files and subdirectories( two subfolders).

```
| | |-class1.php
| | \-class2.php
| |-subdir1
| | |-class11.php
| | \-class22.php
| |-subdir2
| | \-class33.php
```

it contains total 5 files.

scanning files in directory is not big issue...but how can i deliver a class relationship between them.

i want array in this form.

array([0]=>classname=>class1,extends=>class2,implements=>[0]class11[1]class22,[1]=>classname=>class2,extends=>class33,implements=>NULL)

HINT:  it can be done through reflection class.

can anyone help me?i need this script..
thanks

Comment: Your hint about reflection implies you know how to go about this, what have you tried?

Comment: i have tried reflection methods(getInterfaceNames() and getParentClass) but problem is how to scan directory for classes and form a array with relationship between them...

Answer (score 0):

Extract from all the files parts of code that look like `class<something but not }>{<something perhaps containing nested {}>}` and eval all of those pieces of code.

I guess you will have to determine specific order in which to eval them (you might take a note which files include which to determine this order, or take a look at `extends` and `implements`)

Then use reflection.